# Fail-fast json4s serialisation of sealed trait and object enum when missing serializer

Tags: scala, serialization, reflection, json4s

### Set up

I'm using json4s 3.2.11 and Scala 2.11.

I have an enumeration defined using `sealed trait`, and a custom serializer for it:

```scala
import org.json4s.CustomSerializer
import org.json4s.JsonAST.JString
import org.json4s.DefaultFormats
import org.json4s.jackson.Serialization

sealed trait Foo
case object X extends Foo
case object Y extends Foo

object FooSerializer
    extends CustomSerializer[Foo](
      _ =>
        ({
          case JString("x") => X
          case JString("y") => Y
        }, {
          case X => JString("x")
          case Y => JString("y")
        })
    )
```

This is great, and works well when added to the formats:

```scala
{
  implicit val formats = DefaultFormats + FooSerializer
  Serialization.write(X) // "x"
}
```

This is great!

### Problem

If the serializer is not added to the formats, json4s will use reflection to create a default representation of the fields, which is extremely unhelpful for these `object`s that don't have fields. It does this silently, seemingly without a way to control it.

```scala
{
  implicit val formats = DefaultFormats
  Serialization.write(X) // {}
}
```

This is a problematic, as there's no indication of what's gone wrong until much later. This invalid/useless data might be sent around the network or written to databases, if tests don't happen to catch it. And, this may be exposed publicly from a library, meaning downstream users have to remember it as well.

NB. this is different to `read`, which throws an exception on failure, since the `Foo` trait doesn't have any useful constructors:

```scala
{
  implicit val formats = DefaultFormats
  Serialization.read[Foo]("\"x\"")
}
```

```
org.json4s.package$MappingException: No constructor for type Foo, JString(x)
  at org.json4s.Extraction$ClassInstanceBuilder.org$json4s$Extraction$ClassInstanceBuilder$$constructor(Extraction.scala:417)
  at org.json4s.Extraction$ClassInstanceBuilder.org$json4s$Extraction$ClassInstanceBuilder$$instantiate(Extraction.scala:468)
  at org.json4s.Extraction$ClassInstanceBuilder$$anonfun$result$6.apply(Extraction.scala:515)
...
```

### Question

Is there a way to either disable the default `{}` formatting for these objects, or to "bake" in the formatting to the object itself?

For instance, having `write` throw an exception like `read` would be fine, as it would flag the problem to the caller immediately.

Answer (score 3):

There is an old [open issue](https://github.com/json4s/json4s/issues/66) which seems to ask similar question where one of the [contributors](https://github.com/json4s/json4s/issues/66#issuecomment-24282405) suggests to

> you need to create a custom deserializer or serializer

which makes it sound there is no out-of-the-box way to alter the default behaviour.

#### Method 1: Disallow default formats via Scalastyle

Try disallowing import of `org.json4s.DefaultFormats` using Scalastyle [`IllegalImportsChecker`](http://www.scalastyle.org/rules-1.0.0.html#org_scalastyle_scalariform_IllegalImportsChecker)

```
 <check level="error" class="org.scalastyle.scalariform.IllegalImportsChecker" enabled="true">
  <parameters>
   <customMessage>Import from illegal package: Please use example.DefaultFormats instead of org.json4s.DefaultFormats</customMessage>
   <parameter name="illegalImports"><![CDATA[org.json4s.DefaultFormats]]></parameter>
  </parameters>
 </check>
```

and provide custom `DefaultFormats` like so

```
package object example {
  val DefaultFormats = Serialization.formats(NoTypeHints) + FooSerializer
}
```

which would allow us to serialise ADTs like so

```
import example.DefaultFormats
implicit val formats = DefaultFormats
case class Bar(foo: Foo)
println(Serialization.write(Bar(X)))
println(Serialization.write(X))
println(Serialization.write(Y))
```

which should output

```
{"foo":"x"}
"x"
"y"
```

If we try to import `org.json4s.DefaultFormats`, then Scalastyle should raise the following error:

```
Import from illegal package: Please use example.DefaultFormats instead of org.json4s.DefaultFormats
```

#### Method 2: Bake in serialisation for non-nested values

Perhaps we could "bake in" the formatting into objects by defining `write` method in `Foo` which delegates to `Serialization.write` like so

```
sealed trait Foo {
  object FooSerializer extends CustomSerializer[Foo](_ =>
      ({
        case JString("x") => X
        case JString("y") => Y
      }, {
        case X => JString("x")
        case Y => JString("y")
      })
  )

  def write: String = 
    Serialization.write(this)(DefaultFormats + FooSerializer)
}
case object X extends Foo
case object Y extends Foo
```

Note how we hardcoded passing `FooSerializer` format to `write`. Now we can serialise with

```
println(X.write)
println(Y.write)
```

which should output

```
"x"
"y"
```

#### Method 3: Provide custom `DefaultFormats` alongside `org.json4s.DefaultFormats`

We could also try defining custom `DefaultFormats` in our own package like so

```
package example

object DefaultFormats extends DefaultFormats {
  override val customSerializers: List[Serializer[_]] = List(FooSerializer)
}
```

which would allow us to serialise ADTs like so

```
import example.DefaultFormats
implicit val formats = DefaultFormats
case class Bar(foo: Foo)
println(Serialization.write(Bar(X)))
println(Serialization.write(X))
println(Serialization.write(Y))
```

which should output

```
{"foo":"x"}
"x"
"y"
```

Having two default formats, `org.json4s.DefaultFormats` and `example.DefaultFormats`, would at least make the user have to choose between the two, if say, they use IDE to auto-import them.

Comment: The `write` approach is nice for converting individual values, but I think it doesn't work for nested values (if I've got `case class Bar(foo: Foo)`, it should serialise to `{"foo": "x"}`, not `{"foo": {}}`), and one still has to remember to use that `write` function. Thanks for finding the issue! It is... unfortunate that it has been open for almost 6 years.

Comment: I've edited the answer with Scalastyle method which would allow nested-ADT serialisation as well as enabling users to continue using `write`.

Comment: Nice; the scalastyle method is interesting! I think that's a reasonable work around, but I'm not a huge fan, as it does require anyone using the library to do that set-up (but at least that's only one time). 

How does method 3 differ to method 1? It seems like it's just an alternative way to specify an appropriate `DefaultFormats` object (as an `object` instead of a `val`), and still requires some sort of enforcement (e.g. via `scalastyle`)?